# I want to update year like 2011-2014 in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update year like 2011-2014 in sql

update batch b set batch_name= 2011-2014 where id=1;

Comment: Using sql query browser

Comment: Using MYSQL Query browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `2011-2014` in single quote `'` as this is a string like this `'2011-2014'` and then try:

```
UPDATE batch b SET batch_name= '2011-2014' WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: Welcome If you got your ans please accept and upvote :-) @Anamika